# Server freezes when uploading large sized images in php

Tags: php, image, file, file-upload, server

I have simple html form with post method, which sends an image to my action.php file:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

And my action.php file looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
      $error = $_FILES['avatar']['error'];
      echo $error;
}
```

It works fine with small sized images, but when I try to submit images with approximately 2mb size the server just stops responding. It even doesn't send post request to my action.php.

**Note:** I've already set my upload_max_filesize = 64M, but the same thing is happening. It doesn't show any errors

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `post_max_size = 70M`.
*Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize*.

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

If problem persist you could try these solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache?lq=1),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)).

Comment: Have you check the above links?

Comment: May it be because the IDE that I'm using?

Comment: What about `max_execution_time` and  `max_input_time` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: max_execution_time=120, max_input_time=60

Comment: Can you try `300` for both of them?