# How to I send a base64 string that is 200000+ characters long, to a PHP function so I can save the image

Tags: javascript, php, base64

So I'm using [Cropper](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) to let a user resize and do some stuff to an image. The edited image is in a canvas element which I run `.toDataURL()` on. This creates a base64 string of the 'finished product'.

I need to **programmatically** save the edited image to a folder on the server.

I can't do this with an `$.ajax` request because I can't pass such a long query via a `$_POST/$_GET` command.

Some other details/information:

- this is a WordPress website (not that this makes a difference, I dont think)
- the edited image is about 300x300
- i need to support IE9 so client-side file-saving isn't an option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload large files using php, apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a base64 string, you could use chuncking, i.e. split the string and send it in small portions to the server via ajax. You need to think about signalising "start" and "end"

Comment: Interesting angle, thanks @svrnm. Will wait a bit longer to see if any other ideas come in and then give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

*facepalm

Used $.post instead... Works now :)