# Upload big files in php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I need to upload big files from my website (music albums). The problem is that I can't upgrade my server speed and usually for those big files connection goes down (too much time for response, timeout). I could change php.ini stats but usually music albums need 5-10 min for upload. Which simple solution can you suggest me?

Comment: First step is to make sure that you have a legal right to distribute these music albums

Comment: Now you have put the cat amoungst the pidgeons @MarkBaker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload large files using php, apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache)

Comment: Please see this answer providing a list of solutions (and next time use the search function): http://stackoverflow.com/a/37915378/2343558

Comment: I was asking another way instead of changing the php.ini. How does asynchro upload works?