# Error in uploading large file (php)

Tags: php

So I have a large file I need to upload via php (~1gb). After uploading the file I'm using php for further analysis.

My code works for smaller files. Is there a way to solve this issue? I changed php.ini to accommodate the upload of large file size but it still fails.

Update: I tried doing what people suggested in [upload large files using php, apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache) and it still does not work.

Comment: this is a very common issue. there are file size limits. this question will be closed shortly

Comment: yes i looked at the questions previously asked and edited my php.ini for max_upload_filesize and post_max_filesize. But it still does not work

Comment: because that is not the only thing that restricts large file. look at apache settings if you are using apache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload large files using php, apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache)

Comment: Useful tip: Use <?php phpinfo(); to confirm you are editing the right php.ini file.  Also consider time out values and if you have enough space in the temporary folder where uploads are initially saved.

Comment: is it possible its not uploading the file because of time-out? as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache