# "You probably tried to upload a file that is too large." when trying to import a database file to myphpadmin (Windows 10)

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying to run a PHP website (Prestashop 1.4) locally using XAMPP. I copied all the data from public_html and put it in htdocs.

When I tried to use phpmyadmin to import the database, it said that the file was too large. I went to the ini file and changed

> myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

to

> myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1500M

I tried to import the file again, and it said :

> You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.

Is there another way to bypass that limit?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you import/upload your file via PHP? If so, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache and adjust your php.ini settings to your needs.

Comment: No, the files are local to my computer. I did those edits and it still says it's too large.

Comment: phpmyadmin sucks, and I believe has a 50MB limit on that kind of thing. Download HeidiSQL and import from that.

Comment: @delboy1978uk if anything sucks here, it's your understanding how things work. There's no 50MB hard limit.

Comment: @Morgoth If you upload the files via phpmyadmin, then a script of phpmyadmin is probably executed ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import database through phpmyadmin file size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593128/cant-import-database-through-phpmyadmin-file-size-too-large)

Comment: @delboy1978uk Sorry for being a noob, but wouldn't that mess around with everything else on XAMPP? Or is it just a php administration tool..I want to do what you're saying though.

Comment: It's just a website that connects to your MySQL. You can use any tool, it won't affect anything.

Comment: I don't understand what is happening. I made the limit 1,5GB, it even shows in the little upload bar. Now I get this error when I try to upload a database of 19MB. https://imgur.com/a/EEt5V

Comment: OK I managed to find the problem while browsing a prestashop forum thread from 2010. I re-exported the SQL file from the original store, this time checked the box next to "Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION" under "structure". The importing worked. Thanks all for your suggestions

Comment: This works for me when I need to import a large sql file. `mysql -u root -p; source /directory/where/file/exists/file.sql;`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `MySQL` in `Xampp` then do the steps below.
Find the following in `php.ini` file

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

And change their sizes according to your need. I'm using these values

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 30M
max_execution_time = 4500
max_input_time = 4500
memory_limit = 850M
```

**Note:1** `upload_max_filesize` is essential **But** it's better to change all.

**Note:2** You must restart apache service.