# Is it possible to read object from AJAX request on server side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

Actually, I'm trying to send video file in base64 but it the file is large (small files works fine) that's why ajax process not completed and I got 400 error.

So, I thought to send a file object like below so, I can read this object from the server-side. But I don't know if it is possible? OR is there any way through which I can handle large video file upload?

```js
[object FileReader]
```

And here is my AJAX Code

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
// this function is triggered once a call to readAsDataURL returns
reader.onload = async function(event){
   var fileData = new FormData();
    var fileType;
    fileType = ".avi";
    // console.log(my_script_vars.postID);
    // fileData.append("file", event.target);
    fileData.append("file", event.target.result);
    fileData.append("action", "myaction");
    fileData.append("filetype", fileType);
    fileData.append("post_id", my_script_vars.postID);
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.reelme.app/sign-up/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: fileData,  
        type: 'POST',
        .......
        .......
        .......
    });
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send a javascript object to a server as a JSON object. Have you tried using JSON.stringify(object)?

Comment: Yes, I tried JSON.stringify(object) but no luck. Actually, this way works if we pass javascript array JSON.stringify(array) but that why I faced same large file 400 error

Comment: maybe [increasing maximum post size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size) might help.

Comment: Already did this. But no luck.

Comment: can you check if the url in the ajax call is correct?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700207/upload-large-files-using-php-apache

Comment: Yes, URL is correct in AJAX call as I have mentioned in my problem is that small files uploading fine.

Comment: I want to confirm more here that, when video is large then AJAX request can't reach to server end it breaks between and error occurred 400.

Comment: Also, I got another idea to upload video is to use BLOB url like blob:https://www.reelme.app/ede8b30e-7d70-4e30-a05e-557b7260f796 but when I tried to read its content using file_get_contents it returns nothing. 

Do you guys have any idea how to get content from BLOB URL on server side?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't read the file into base64 and store everything in memory. screw that FileReader you have.

you are doing the right thing by using FormData, but a FormData can also append blob & files

```js
// Simulate a file you would normally get from a file input or drag n drop
const file = new File(['abc'], 'sample.txt', { type: 'text/plain' })

const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('file', file)
```

then to upload it i would suggest that you use fetch instead of jQuery that requires all those processData & other config

```js
const url = 'https://www.reelme.app/sign-up/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: fd })
  .then(console.log, console.error)
```

JSON isn't meant to handle large binary data... b/c it's no good streaming format.

Comment: Thanks brother. I already did this like you described. I used below code.

Comment: function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
 
    var arr = dataurl.split(','),
        mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), 
        n = bstr.length, 
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}